# Is possible to protect variable from overriding in Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter

First of all I would like to apologise for my english.
I'm here to ask something about php and ci3. I'm writing a program who can be integrated from someone else want to write a part of code, like plugins.
In my code I have a MY_Controller controller who contains a public "$_idUtente". This var contains the user id. I use this var to have a FOREIGN KEY in SQL to associate the records with the user id.
In the __construct of My_Controller I set this variable with the session value, after login with ion_auth library.

Here is it the trouble. If someone else write a part of code and overwrite the value of $_idUtente, they can insert a value who maybe read the datas of another user. I read on php.net about the final keyboard, but it isn't for variables.
Anyone can help me about this?
I need to write my part of core system and protect this variable from overriding.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not entirely clear.
I suggest you to use a *private* variable and a getter method to read the variable

```
class abc {

   private $_idUtente;

   function __construct () {
      $this->_idUtente = getTheUserIdFromSomewhere();
   }

   public function getIdUtente(){
      return $this->_idUtente;
   }
}
```

### **Update.**

Since PHP 8.1 you can use single *readonly* properties. Try taking a look at [this article](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/readonly) that well explains how they work, to see if they are right for you.

Comment: @redenfire I prefer to reply in English to allow people from other countries to read the messages and participate if they wish.
The context is not very clear, *"I have to develop an application that contains others"* means everything and nothing :-) . If the "applications" share some code then they are parts of the same application. However there is no other way to solve the problem: in PHP an attribute can be public, protected or private. The only way to protect the attribute is the one indicated, you should adapt your code so from other parties $_Userid can only be accessed via a getter.

Comment: I understood, I write in english. I try to make a "core application". This app can used to connect another apps in the system, together. for example, I stock a list of italian municipals in db, and other apps can read this list with a standard created on the "core" application. Every users into apps have a level, and the user info are saved into sessions datas (like UserId and UserLevels). another dev who use the core app for make a personal app, in my case, can overwrite the UserId and UserLevels into session and "change" the permession of accesses. This is what I want to protect.

Comment: From how you describe your setup, it looks like a single application composed by a main core and some additional features. They share the environment and the session too. In this scenario it's not easy (and perhaps not possible) to mantain completely separated entities.
Perhaps you have to refactor your code in the way I showed you. Or better the entire projet should be revised in a microservices-like mode (but this it's not a walk in the park)

Comment: The phrase "the way i showed you" is about setter method? About the microservices, I'm thinking about it. Can you give me something to try or study, on the base of your experience?

Comment: @redenfire Yes private property with getter. I had a look at the readonly properties also, try see my update in the answer. About microservices I can't help you.